# Js script doesn't read default value moment.js

Tags: javascript, dom, onchange, momentjs

I made a little page to track project times and write them into a database. I have two input fields for start and end time that will be calculated via a small JS script and the help of moment.js to show the total hrs. When there are values in the database already they are placed into the input fields as default value. When I now just tab through the input fields the script will calculate the value 0. I inspected the DOM and on both input fields it is correctly showing the right timestamps for both value and defaultvalue. What am I missing, and why is the JS triggered if I set it to be onChange?

JS

```
function TimeDifference(a) {
var start = moment(document.getElementById('Start_'+a).value,'HH:mm');
var stop = moment(document.getElementById('Finish_'+a).value,'HH:mm');
document.getElementById('sum'+a).value =  moment.duration(stop-start).asHours();}
```

HTML

```
<input  class='timebox' type='text' id='Start_" . $i . "' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event) ' onChange='TimeDifference(" . $i . ")' value='{$db_start}' >
<input  class='timebox' type='text' id='Finish_" . $i . "' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='TimeDifference(" . $i . ")' value='{$db_stop}'>
<input id='sum" . $i . "' class='sumbox' readonly disabled='disabled' style='border:0px;'>
```

Comment: Could you please be so kind to provide a complete code example, so that we could try out our ideas, before giving you an answer? ;) Consider using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking why the `onchange` event triggers when the input loses focus? If that is your question I'm guessing it has something to do with what `isNumberKey(event)` does.

Comment: Well my question is priarily why is the script calculating with 0 or empty values when these are loaded from the database on opening the page secondary I am surprised that even though I am just tabbing through the fields the script gets run - so tab counts as change?

Comment: Eric, I am trying to clean all that php stuff out to get it to run in JSfiddle. But somehow my script doesnt work at all there :/

Comment: Tabs do not count as change. Again, check what `isNumberKey(event)` does, it's probably what's triggering the `change` event. Also, you'd probably be better off binding these events purely through javascript than mixing html event triggers and javascript. This is probably what's giving you trouble setting up a fiddle too. Regarding that, try jsbin instead.

Comment: Here's an abstracted jsbin of your posted code, showing that the error lies in whatever you haven't posted. http://jsbin.com/hekunusanu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ok not sure what is different in the snippet but on jsbin it works. I took the isNumberKey check out in my original code but it doesnt make a difference.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kecowuwoku/edit?html,js,output

moment.js is in the top part of the JS section my code is at the bottom

Comment: Ok found it. It I had a onblur added to sum all summary hr up whenever I changed one field. With this out the code now works. I have to reconsider how I do the gran total sum script.